# Using guard to check parameters to inits in Swift 2.2

Tags: swift, cocoa, initialization, swift2

Apparently a guard statement will create a new variable that might shadow a property with the same name.

For example, in this code:

```
struct Foo{

    let url : NSURL

    init?(urlString: String){

        guard let url = NSURL(string: urlString) else{
            return nil
        }

        //self.url = url
    }
}
```

It will only compile if you uncomment the last line. Otherwise the compiler will complain that you are leaving self.url unbound.

Is this a bug or a feature? Sounds rather silly to me and forces you to write repetitive code.

Comment: This is a feature. Ideally, you shouldn't be using failing initializers. They were added mainly because of Obj-C compatibility. A better design would be to pass `NSURL` directly to the initializer and handle the parsing before initialization. Or using a static method.

Comment: It's not just `guard`, you can always create a variable in a local scope that shadows a variable or property declared in an outer scope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must initialize all fields of a struct or class before leaving the `init` method.  In this case, you never initialize url (independent of the `guard` statement, so it fails.  This requirement is so that the state of the object can be guaranteed, so destruction is reliable, ie., it's a feature of the language.

In this case, the `guard` statement is assigning the new `NSURL` result to a local stack variable, and not the `url` property, the explicit assignment is necessary to fix that.